# Tinyprog has issues programming the TinyFPGA-BX module on macOS M1

Tags: fpga, lattice

I have used TinyProg on Linux before to program the TinyFPGA-BX board just fine, but I am having issues with macOS on an M1 Powerbook. Apio finds the serial device just fine:

```
apio system --lsserial

Number of Serial devices found: 1
/dev/cu.usbmodem13201
Description: IOUSBHostDevice
Hardware info: USB VID:PID=0483:5740 LOCATION=0-1.3.2
```

But when I do the following to list serial devices with TinyProg, I get this:

```
tinyprog -d 0483:5740 -c /dev/cu.usbmodem13201 -l

TinyProg CLI
------------
Using device id 0483:5740
Boards with active bootloaders:
    No active bootloaders found.  Check USB connections
    and press reset button to activate bootloader.
```

The board works fine on Linux and has a bootloader. I tried updating the bootloader (on macos), but it states it is up-to-date. i.e

```
tinyprog -d 0483:5740 -c /dev/cu.usbmodem13201 --update-bootloader

TinyProg CLI
------------
Using device id 0483:5740
All connected and active boards are up to date!
```

Any ideas anyone?

A thought?
I do have issues with USB running at full speed on the M1, is there a way to slow it down for Tinyprog?

**Update**

Seems using the --pyserial option to tinyprog works. It takes about a minute to start working, but it works ..I do wonder if it is a speed/cable thing .. using the --libusb option results in a programming attempt, but a failure in verify ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem setting up my toolchain on MacBook Air M2.

I do found a workaround but have no clue why it works. Hope someone who understands pyusb more can explain or find a real solution for this.

Go to your tinyprog package `__init__.py` and comment out `if not d.is_kernel_driver_active(1)`

```
def get_ports(device_id):
    ...
    if platform.system() == "Darwin" or use_libusb:
        import usb
        vid, pid = [int(x, 16) for x in device_id.split(":")]
        ports += [
            UsbPort(d)
            for d in usb.core.find(idVendor=vid, idProduct=pid, find_all=True)
            # if not d.is_kernel_driver_active(1)
        ]
    ...
```

for me the file is at `.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tinyprog/__init__.py`

I have successfully upload my program into my TinyFpga BX after remove this check.